# Chrome://inspect/#devices not detecting my ipad air 2

Tags: remote-debugging

I have tried a lot my device(ipad air 2) is not getting detected by chrome in my pc I need to debug some code for my ipad but all is in vain need help.Have downloaded telerik app as well but its detecting the tab but saying not configure for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

iPad will be detected by safari web inspecter.
Preferences - advanced - show web inspector

Comment: in chrome and in windows os

Comment: You can download safari for windows. Another thing, If you are making any hybrid app then it will run in respective device's web view, Which will be its default browser. you should debug with that only

Comment: but the safari web-inspector is present in safari version 6.0 or greater and we cannot have it for windows

Comment: Buy a mac then :D . Anyway how you are running in iPad then?? xcode?? you can try with the bigger resolution in chrome.

Comment: Ipad having chrome doing office work buddy cant ask them to buy mac hope u cn undrstnd